# How to remove any number of non-alphabetical symbols from the beginning of a word?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following words:

```
words = ['001operating', '1002application', '3aaa0225', '-setup', '--setup']
```

I need to drop any non-alphabetic characters before the word. The expected result is this one:

```
processed = ['operating', 'application', 'aaa0225', 'setup', 'setup']
```

This is what I have so far:

```
import re
processed = []
for w in words:
  w = re.sub(r"(?<!\S)", "", w)
  processed.append(w)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `re.sub(r"^[\W\d_]+", "", w)`

Comment: @Silvanas An ECMAScript 5 pattern in the thread you refer to cannot help with `@#Świnka` processing.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Not sure what and why you calling it an ECMAScript 5 pattern, but `w = re.sub(r"^[^a-zA-Z]+", "", w)` expression works very well too as desired by OP. In case you are referring to `(^[^a-zA-Z]+)` then this is a very simple and easy to understand (for a new regexer) regex and supported much widely than `\W` and `\d`. [Check this demo](https://rextester.com/SLLIXX5590)

Comment: @Silvanas `Ś`, `ż`, `Ф`, `ш`,... and `ł` are also letters, and your suggested solution does not handle them. It is not a matter of what is widely used, it is a matter of whether the regex meets the OP requirements or not and `^[^a-zA-Z]+` is not meeting them. VBA is based on ES5 standard, so `re` solution is not necessarily the same all the time as the VBA solution.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: OP's samples do not mention of any Unicode characters. Why assume the solution is needed for Unicode characters too? What if OP wanted Unicode characters to be handled a little differently than you presumed? Also, OP is well familiar with how to code it in python (and use `re`) and all that was needed was a simple regex like I provided one. And for an almost common regex, you don't have to write an answer in EVERY possible language.

Comment: @Silvanas Please calm down. In my language, there are lots of "funny" letters and when I see "non-alphabetical", I actually think "not `ż`, `ł`..." and not just "not `a`, `b`, `c`..." So, Wiktor has got a point.

Comment: @Silvanas In VBA, there is no way to match all letters in a concise way. In Python, there are several ways. And Python `re` and `regex` are so much different from ECMAScript 5 regex implentation that it DOES warrant a separate answer that could be used as a tabstop for all future identical requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
import re
re.sub(r"^[\W\d_]+", "", w)
```

With [PyPi `regex` module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/), you can use

```py
import regex
regex.sub(r"^\P{L}+", "", w)
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string (here, same as `\A`)
- `[\W\d_]+` - matches any non-word, digit or underscore char
- `\P{L}+` - one or more chars other than any Unicode letters.

See a [Python demo](https://tio.run/##fY6xCsIwFEX3fsWjS1uskqY4@gcObg5tlWhjG9Dk8ZoSRfz2mBYFJ4cLhwuHe/Fhe6NL79UNDVkgmYd08h45Q@0AmyphrDAoSViluySHpGCMC8SrOofK6KkqhRCM8/XEy0HaEWf6YBNFSErbFCqSq2E8pRQfqnpft8dmEecQh7gMLobAgdIwLzeQ/Vjh0Fesd8/t66/m/Rs):

```py
import re, regex
words =['001operating', '1002application', '3aaa0225', '-setup', '--setup']

print( [re.sub(r"^[\W\d_]+", "", w) for w in words] )
# => ['operating', 'application', 'aaa0225', 'setup', 'setup']

print( [regex.sub(r"^\P{L}+", "", w) for w in words] )
# => ['operating', 'application', 'aaa0225', 'setup', 'setup']
```